# how can one find the honeypot

Tags: honeypot

how can one find the honeypot 
while want to observe the other hackers.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security. We attempt to do our best to understand / translate when English is not the user's primary language, though this one seems difficult to understand what you are asking. Can you try to rephrase your question(s).

Comment: It looks like you are asking where to find honeypots that you can run yourself. They are easy to find with searches, but you have to figure out what kind of honeypot you want to run. Different types of honeypots have different ways to monitor the attackers your trap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create your own honey pot then you are going to need to have a machine that is directly accessible on the internet but is isolated from your home network. Some sort of VPS would be a good idea however this is not going to be a particularly viable option as VPS providers aren't going to volunteer to have machines on their network being compromised. I don't doubt if they found that you were using one of their VPS machines as a honey pot that your service would be terminated.

However, the honeypot in itself is fairly simple to setup. In order to attract hackers you will need to create a front-end system such as a website that basically looks like an appealing target. The point of the 'honeypot' is to draw hackers in - This means that you need to have a lot of data on your machine that looks legitimate, this way hackers will try and target it.

Once you have setup your vulnerable machine you would simply install the correct monitoring tools and then watch how the hackers behave on the machine. What tool kits they use, how they exploit vulnerabilities, common connection addresses, etc.

**Training Environment**

In the second part of your question where you said:

> i created honeypot want to attack on mine created one .to check the all stuffs

I am going to assume it to mean that you want to create a device that you can exploit and try and break into. Now this part you really need to pay attention to. THIS MUST BE ON YOUR OWN NETWORK. If you attempt to break into a machine that you do not own, even if it is a VPS that you are paying for, if you do not have permission from the hosting company, it represents a breach in the law and is a potentially jail-able offense.

Do not confuse a **honeypot** and a **testing environment** they are two different things and should be managed in very different ways.

Comment: dear what if i try the others honeypot,in my opinion honeypot are available on internet one can use the honeypot to just saw the all operations going through that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean

Comment: also if with another laptop from another area i want to attack on that my created one honeypot.then its possible???

Comment: dear sorry for my illogical question.so if i dont want to create any honeypot.whats the other way to check the hackers on honeypot ?

Comment: any software to check the honeypots on network im using.....

Comment: You could use programs such as wireshark to monitor the traffic between machines on your network. This will show you the servers that are being communicated with. Look some more into computer forensics.